# Light Gallery Plugin Issue on Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I have a website. On one of the pages I had integrated the Light Box Image Gallery plugin. It's working fine on all other browsers accept safari. The issue that I am facing in Safari is when you click on any of the images it will trigger full screen but there is a transition issue on opening and closing the image gallery the page's UI get's distorted.

I have tried all the possible ways even went through github's light box gallery issue tracker unfortunately I am not able to find any solution. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
 <li class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.5s"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#img_gallery">gallery</a></li>



 <div id="img_gallery" class="tab-pane fade">
                            <div class="residential_gallery">
                                <h1>The Pavilion Image Gallery</h1>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="item col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" data-src="assets/images/residential-projects/pavillion_elevation/pavilion_res_elevation0.jpg">
                                    <div class="gal_img"> <img src="assets/images/residential-projects/pavillion_elevation/pavilion_res_elevation0.jpg"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" data-src="assets/images/residential-projects/pavillion_elevation/pavilion_res_elevation1.jpg">
                                    <div class="gal_img"> <img src="assets/images/residential-projects/pavillion_elevation/pavilion_res_elevation1.jpg"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" data-src="assets/images/residential-projects/pavillion_elevation/pavilion_res_elevation2.jpg">
                                    <div class="gal_img"> <img src="assets/images/residential-projects/pavillion_elevation/pavilion_res_elevation2.jpg"></div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="item col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" data-src="assets/images/residential-projects/pavillion_elevation/pavilion_res_elevation3.jpg">
                                    <div class="gal_img"> <img src="assets/images/residential-projects/pavillion_elevation/pavilion_res_elevation3.jpg"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" data-src="assets/images/gallery-images/Pavilion_modal.JPG">
                                    <div class="gal_img"> <img src="assets/images/gallery-images/Pavilion_modal.JPG" /></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" data-src="assets/images/gallery-images/pavilion_modal_1.JPG">
                                    <div class="gal_img"> <img src="assets/images/gallery-images/pavilion_modal_1.JPG" /></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" data-src="assets/images/gallery-images/pavilion_modal_2.JPG">
                                    <div class="gal_img"> <img src="assets/images/gallery-images/pavilion_modal_2.JPG" /></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" data-src="assets/images/gallery-images/pavilion_modal_3.JPG">
                                    <div class="gal_img"> <img src="assets/images/gallery-images/pavilion_modal_3.JPG" /></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

     <script>
        $('.images_gallery, .residential_gallery').lightGallery({
            selector: '.item',
            mode: 'lg-slide',
            cssEasing: 'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1)',
            backdropDuration: 150,
            escKey: true,
            controls: true,
            mousewheel: true,
            thumbnail: false,
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            download: false,
            animateThumb: true,
            counter: true,
            closable: true,
            enableDrag: true,
            zoom: false,
            fullScreen: false
            // scale: 5
        });
        var $lg = $('.images_gallery, .residential_gallery');
        $lg.on('onAfterOpen.lg', function() {
            $lg.data('lightGallery').modules.fullscreen.requestFullscreen();
        });
    </script>


    Not showing and expected error messages on the console however only on a Safari Browser gallery transition issue can be seen.
```

Comment: does this also happen on the light gallery page itself?

Comment: No it's not happening on their page. Please help me out as I have been stuck with this issue from a long time.

Comment: Can anyone please help me out with this issue?

Comment: you can only compare their working solution with your implementation and find out where the differences are.

Comment: I had compared but still not able to find the solution. Can you check once if you are using a macbook?

Comment: No, I don't have a Macbook, sorry.